# compilation error about PNG

Tags: pictures

When I tried to compile UMN_Mapserver, I encountered this error:

-undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'-

I am using ubuntu 10.1

How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: The compile error is likely too specific for an answer here. (Try the Mapserver mailing lists: http://www.mapserver.org/community/lists.html .) If you don't need to build Mapserver from source, there's a binary for 10.1 in the ubuntugis PPA. To install, do `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa` then `sudo apt-get update`, and finally install the mapserver binary with `sudo apt-get install mapserver`.

Comment: Why was this moved from SO to here?

Comment: @Chris: My comment was actually made on the [Webmasters site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13946/compilation-error-about-png?noredirect=1). Looks like the question got moved from SO to PW, and now to SF!

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, maybe we should migrate it over to SU for the trifecta.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `libpng`, or you have the 'wrong' version.